# Record a D3 node click as a global variable or a data element on the node?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, global-variables, 2-way-object-databinding

I am working on a D3 force layout where you can click a node at a time to highlight (i.e. change the color of) it and its links. If you click the same node again, it un-highlights if and if you click on a different node it un-highlights the first and then highlights the new node. I can think of two ways to do this and I would like to know which way is the best.

Option A: the way I am currently doing this by having a true/false "clicked" data element on each node that is updated every time you click unclick a node.

Option B: I believe I could also not have any status recorded on the node itself and instead have a "clickedNode" global variable for the node name that I update and compare things to.

Also, is there a way to create a two-way binding of either of those two options so that if you change it, it automatically changes the style/attr of the related node(s)?

Comment: "Best" is subjective. I would go with option A.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what I thought. I know it is often subjective but I wanted to know if there was a least a common practice that I was going against. I am fine going against common practice if I have a good reason but not fine going against it out of pure ignorance of what the common practice is. I continue using Option A.